# status of the "arguments[n] cannot be set if n is greater than the number of formal or actual parameters" bug?

Tags: javascript

It's possible to set the individual elements of a function `arguments` property (what Mozilla calls an 'array-like' property), however Mozilla reports it is not possible to add elements to this property in SpiderMonkey 1.5 though this is fixed in 1.6 (ref. the note on SpiderMonkey here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

This is a useful property, chaining constructors from subclasses, creating a list of arguments to pass to a function (e.g., `myclassmethod.apply(this, arguments)`), etc.

However I've found V8 will not extend the length in the same way Mozilla reports of SpiderMonkey 1.5.  (Not sure what the status is with other JavaScript engines, Opera, Rhino, etc.).

Is this actually an ECMA feature?  Has Mozilla got it wrong in considering this a bug, or does V8 have a bug to fix?

[Update] I've found using V8 that the `arguments.length` property can be assigned to, and so effectively `arguments` can be extended (or set to whatever length you require otherwise).  However JSLint does complain this is a bad assignment.

[Update] Some test code if anyone wants to try this in Opera, FF etc., create an instance of a subclass calling the constructor with one arg while adding an element to `arguments` in the subclass constructor and calling the superclass constructor, the superclass should report two arguments:

```
function MyClass() {
    if (arguments.length) {
        console.log("arguments.length === " + arguments.length);
        console.log("arguments[0] === " + arguments[0]);
        console.log("arguments[1] === " + arguments[1]);
    }
}

function MySubClass() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
    //arguments.length = 2;  // uncomment to test extending `length' property works
    arguments[1] = 2;
    MyClass.apply(this, arguments);
}

MySubClass.prototype = new MyClass();

new MySubClass(1);
```

[Update] JSLint actually complains when you make any kind of assignment to `arguments` by the looks (e.g., `arguments[0] = "foo"`).  So maybe JSLint has some work to do here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can make the arguments object into a standard array:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

[EDIT] so you could do:

```
myclassmethod.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0).push(newValue));
```

Comment: I'm looking to do this in reverse - to set the contents of `arguments` itself from an array, so I can call `myfunc(arguments)` (which will call `myfunc` with the contents of `arguments` as parameters).  There is no other way to my knowledge of calling a function if you do not know what the args to the function are going to be.  (The context is writing a quick module to simplify the process testing classes/functions and the need to call a function with test data stored in an array - generically as well so that any function/method can be tested without prior knowledge of arity).

Comment: I've haven't defacto tested it but that would only pass an array to `myclassmethod` as the first argument, not the argument list itself, which rather magically `arguments` does.

Comment: i can understand how it might look that way, but passing an array of values to the .call() does in-fact pass each item of the array as a separate argument, same as an arguments object.  try it! ;-)

Comment: OK! you are right, `.apply` will indeed take an array of arguments to make the call with... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply - I'm a tad rusty!  Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

ECMA-262 10.1.8 says that the prototype of the `arguments` object is the Object prototype and that the `arguments` object is initialized in a certain way, using the phrase "initial value".  So, it would seem like you could assign any of its properties to whatever you want.  I'm not sure if that's the correct interpretation though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think we can conclude on this one.

Running the above example code on FF, Comodo Dragon, Opera and IE (all current version, Windoze) they will all accept a change of the `arguments.length` property to resize the (as Mozilla phrases this, 'array-like') `arguemnts` object.  None will increase the size by assigning a value as is usual for an array (i.e., `arguments[arguments.length] = "new arg"`).

It seems the consensus of the javascript engines is that as an 'array-like' object `arguments` behaves like an array, but is otherwise inclined to throw a few surprises ;)  Either way the interpretation of the ECMA standard appears to be on the face of it at least consistent across the board, and so the semantics are not really an issue (the whys and wherefores being the only remaining question but of historical interest only).

Neither MSDN nor Mozilla seem to have this documented (not sure where V8 or Opera hide their JS docs) - in a nutshell to conclude some documentation would definitely not go amiss.  At which point I will bow out, however if someone could opportunistically drop the hint to the relevant parties at some point it is a useful technique to use once in a while.

Thanks for all who have taken the time to look at this question.

[Update] BishopZ has pointed out above that `.apply` will take an array of arguments anyway (this has slipped my mind since I last used it many years ago, and which solves my problem).  However the 'array-like' `arguments` can still be used, and might even be preferable in some situations (easier for example to pop a value onto, or just to pass on arguments to a superclass).  Thanks again for looking at the issue.